# terraform data source cannot able fetch from remote backend

Tags: object, attributes, terraform

i am using AWS cloud and deployed all resources using terraform 0.12.29 manually with terraform apply. Our automation tool has terraform 0.12.20, and when I try to deploy using automation tool it wont able to do because of tfstate deployed with higher version.
so i moved tfstate from s3 backend and then use tfenv to downgrade my laptop terraform version to 0.12.20 and run 'terraform init' and 'terraform refresh' to update the remote backend.

but it doesn't seem to be like, because whenever I was trying to query data source, getting this error:-

Error: Unsupported attribute

on billpro.tf line 26, in module "my-apps":
26:   ecs_cluster = data.terraform_remote_state.production.outputs.ecs_cluster_name
|----------------
| data.terraform_remote_state.production.outputs is object with 11 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "ecs_cluster_name".

the problem is resources are deployed and running, in fact i lost my tfstate file aswell. is there a way to update tfstate on s3 backend with the running resources and resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your s3 tfstate file is not up to date , you will have to point to it and import all the missing resources with "terraform import". There is no other workaround.